# Babel 7 disable --isolatedModules Typescript flag?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, babeljs, create-react-app

How can I disable --isolatedModules flag in Babel 7, it causes everything to crash. It crashes on:

- 'use strict'
- const enums, which are used by CRA's own dependencies (chalk) also fail so im not sure whats going on there

My webpack config, removed imports to hit word limit. I've tried disabling it my tsconfig but I think babel is ignoring that.

```js
'use strict';
// Source maps are resource heavy and can cause out of memory issue for large source files.
const shouldUseSourceMap = process.env.GENERATE_SOURCEMAP !== 'false';
// Some apps do not need the benefits of saving a web request, so not inlining the chunk
// makes for a smoother build process.
const shouldInlineRuntimeChunk = process.env.INLINE_RUNTIME_CHUNK !== 'false';

// Check if TypeScript is setup
const useTypeScript = fs.existsSync(paths.appTsConfig);

// style files regexes
const cssRegex = /\.css$/;
const cssModuleRegex = /\.module\.css$/;
const sassRegex = /\.(scss|sass)$/;
const sassModuleRegex = /\.module\.(scss|sass)$/;

// This is the production and development configuration.
// It is focused on developer experience, fast rebuilds, and a minimal bundle.
module.exports = function(webpackEnv) {
  const isEnvDevelopment = webpackEnv === 'development';
  const isEnvProduction = webpackEnv === 'production';

  // Webpack uses `publicPath` to determine where the app is being served from.
  // It requires a trailing slash, or the file assets will get an incorrect path.
  // In development, we always serve from the root. This makes config easier.
  const publicPath = isEnvProduction
    ? paths.servedPath
    : isEnvDevelopment && '/';
  // Some apps do not use client-side routing with pushState.
  // For these, "homepage" can be set to "." to enable relative asset paths.
  const shouldUseRelativeAssetPaths = publicPath === './';

  // `publicUrl` is just like `publicPath`, but we will provide it to our app
  // as %PUBLIC_URL% in `index.html` and `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` in JavaScript.
  // Omit trailing slash as %PUBLIC_URL%/xyz looks better than %PUBLIC_URL%xyz.
  const publicUrl = isEnvProduction
    ? publicPath.slice(0, -1)
    : isEnvDevelopment && '';
  // Get environment variables to inject into our app.
  const env = getClientEnvironment(publicUrl);

  // common function to get style loaders
  const getStyleLoaders = (cssOptions, preProcessor) => {
    const loaders = [
      isEnvDevelopment && require.resolve('style-loader'),
      isEnvProduction && {
        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
        options: Object.assign(
          {},
          shouldUseRelativeAssetPaths ? { publicPath: '../../' } : undefined
        ),
      },
      {
        loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
        options: cssOptions,
      },
      {
        // Options for PostCSS as we reference these options twice
        // Adds vendor prefixing based on your specified browser support in
        // package.json
        loader: require.resolve('postcss-loader'),
        options: {
          // Necessary for external CSS imports to work
          // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2677
          ident: 'postcss',
          plugins: () => [
            require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
            require('postcss-preset-env')({
              autoprefixer: {
                flexbox: 'no-2009',
              },
              stage: 3,
            }),
          ],
          sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
        },
      },
    ].filter(Boolean);
    if (preProcessor) {
      loaders.push({
        loader: require.resolve(preProcessor),
        options: {
          sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
        },
      });
    }
    return loaders;
  };

  return {
    mode: isEnvProduction ? 'production' : isEnvDevelopment && 'development',
    // Stop compilation early in production
    bail: isEnvProduction,
    devtool: isEnvProduction
      ? shouldUseSourceMap
        ? 'source-map'
        : false
      : isEnvDevelopment && 'cheap-module-source-map',
    // These are the "entry points" to our application.
    // This means they will be the "root" imports that are included in JS bundle.
    entry: [
      // Include an alternative client for WebpackDevServer. A client's job is to
      // connect to WebpackDevServer by a socket and get notified about changes.
      // When you save a file, the client will either apply hot updates (in case
      // of CSS changes), or refresh the page (in case of JS changes). When you
      // make a syntax error, this client will display a syntax error overlay.
      // Note: instead of the default WebpackDevServer client, we use a custom one
      // to bring better experience for Create React App users. You can replace
      // the line below with these two lines if you prefer the stock client:
      // require.resolve('webpack-dev-server/client') + '?/',
      // require.resolve('webpack/hot/dev-server'),
      isEnvDevelopment &&
        require.resolve('react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient'),
      // Finally, this is your app's code:
      paths.appIndexJs,
      // We include the app code last so that if there is a runtime error during
      // initialization, it doesn't blow up the WebpackDevServer client, and
      // changing JS code would still trigger a refresh.
    ].filter(Boolean),
    output: {
      // The build folder.
      path: isEnvProduction ? paths.appBuild : undefined,
      // Add /* filename */ comments to generated require()s in the output.
      pathinfo: isEnvDevelopment,
      // There will be one main bundle, and one file per asynchronous chunk.
      // In development, it does not produce real files.
      filename: isEnvProduction
        ? 'static/js/[name].[chunkhash:8].js'
        : isEnvDevelopment && 'static/js/bundle.js',
      // There are also additional JS chunk files if you use code splitting.
      chunkFilename: isEnvProduction
        ? 'static/js/[name].[chunkhash:8].chunk.js'
        : isEnvDevelopment && 'static/js/[name].chunk.js',
      // We inferred the "public path" (such as / or /my-project) from homepage.
      // We use "/" in development.
      publicPath: publicPath,
      // Point sourcemap entries to original disk location (format as URL on Windows)
      devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: isEnvProduction
        ? info =>
            path
              .relative(paths.appSrc, info.absoluteResourcePath)
              .replace(/\\/g, '/')
        : isEnvDevelopment &&
          (info => path.resolve(info.absoluteResourcePath).replace(/\\/g, '/')),
    },
    optimization: {
      minimize: isEnvProduction,
      minimizer: [
        // This is only used in production mode
        new TerserPlugin({
          terserOptions: {
            parse: {
              // we want terser to parse ecma 8 code. However, we don't want it
              // to apply any minfication steps that turns valid ecma 5 code
              // into invalid ecma 5 code. This is why the 'compress' and 'output'
              // sections only apply transformations that are ecma 5 safe
              // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/4234
              ecma: 8,
            },
            compress: {
              ecma: 5,
              warnings: false,
              // Disabled because of an issue with Uglify breaking seemingly valid code:
              // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2376
              // Pending further investigation:
              // https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/issues/2011
              comparisons: false,
              // Disabled because of an issue with Terser breaking valid code:
              // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5250
              // Pending futher investigation:
              // https://github.com/terser-js/terser/issues/120
              inline: 2,
            },
            mangle: {
              safari10: true,
            },
            output: {
              ecma: 5,
              comments: false,
              // Turned on because emoji and regex is not minified properly using default
              // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2488
              ascii_only: true,
            },
          },
          // Use multi-process parallel running to improve the build speed
          // Default number of concurrent runs: os.cpus().length - 1
          parallel: true,
          // Enable file caching
          cache: true,
          sourceMap: shouldUseSourceMap,
        }),
        // This is only used in production mode
        new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({
          cssProcessorOptions: {
            parser: safePostCssParser,
            map: shouldUseSourceMap
              ? {
                  // `inline: false` forces the sourcemap to be output into a
                  // separate file
                  inline: false,
                  // `annotation: true` appends the sourceMappingURL to the end of
                  // the css file, helping the browser find the sourcemap
                  annotation: true,
                }
              : false,
          },
        }),
      ],
      // Automatically split vendor and commons
      // https://twitter.com/wSokra/status/969633336732905474
      // https://medium.com/webpack/webpack-4-code-splitting-chunk-graph-and-the-splitchunks-optimization-be739a861366
      splitChunks: {
        chunks: 'all',
        name: false,
      },
      // Keep the runtime chunk separated to enable long term caching
      // https://twitter.com/wSokra/status/969679223278505985
      runtimeChunk: true,
    },
    resolve: {
      // This allows you to set a fallback for where Webpack should look for modules.
      // We placed these paths second because we want `node_modules` to "win"
      // if there are any conflicts. This matches Node resolution mechanism.
      // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/253
      modules: ['node_modules'].concat(
        // It is guaranteed to exist because we tweak it in `env.js`
        process.env.NODE_PATH.split(path.delimiter).filter(Boolean),
      ),
      // These are the reasonable defaults supported by the Node ecosystem.
      // We also include JSX as a common component filename extension to support
      // some tools, although we do not recommend using it, see:
      // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/290
      // `web` extension prefixes have been added for better support
      // for React Native Web.
      extensions: paths.moduleFileExtensions
        .map(ext => `.${ext}`)
        .filter(ext => useTypeScript || !ext.includes('ts')),
      alias: {
        // Support React Native Web
        // https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/08/a-glimpse-into-the-future-with-react-native-for-web/
        'react-native': 'react-native-web',
        '@': path.join(__dirname, '../src')
      },
      plugins: [
        // Adds support for installing with Plug'n'Play, leading to faster installs and adding
        // guards against forgotten dependencies and such.
        PnpWebpackPlugin,
        // Prevents users from importing files from outside of src/ (or node_modules/).
        // This often causes confusion because we only process files within src/ with babel.
        // To fix this, we prevent you from importing files out of src/ -- if you'd like to,
        // please link the files into your node_modules/ and let module-resolution kick in.
        // Make sure your source files are compiled, as they will not be processed in any way.
        new ModuleScopePlugin([paths.appSrc, paths.appSubmodules], [paths.appPackageJson]),
      ],
    },
    resolveLoader: {
      plugins: [
        // Also related to Plug'n'Play, but this time it tells Webpack to load its loaders
        // from the current package.
        PnpWebpackPlugin.moduleLoader(module),
      ],
    },
    module: {
      strictExportPresence: true,
      rules: [
        // Disable require.ensure as it's not a standard language feature.
        { parser: { requireEnsure: false } },

        // First, run the linter.
        // It's important to do this before Babel processes the JS.
        {
          test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx)$/,
          enforce: 'pre',
          use: [
            {
              options: {
                formatter: require.resolve('react-dev-utils/eslintFormatter'),
                eslintPath: require.resolve('eslint'),
                
              },
              loader: require.resolve('eslint-loader'),
            },
          ],
          include: paths.appSrc,
        },
        {
          // "oneOf" will traverse all following loaders until one will
          // match the requirements. When no loader matches it will fall
          // back to the "file" loader at the end of the loader list.
          oneOf: [
            // "url" loader works like "file" loader except that it embeds assets
            // smaller than specified limit in bytes as data URLs to avoid requests.
            // A missing `test` is equivalent to a match.
            {
              test: [/\.bmp$/, /\.gif$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.png$/],
              loader: require.resolve('url-loader'),
              options: {
                limit: 10000,
                name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
              },
            },
            // Process application JS with Babel.
            // The preset includes JSX, Flow, TypeScript, and some ESnext features.
            {
              test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
              include: [paths.appSrc, paths.appSubmodules],
              loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
              options: {
                customize: require.resolve(
                  'babel-preset-react-app/webpack-overrides'
                ),
                
                plugins: [
                  [
                    require.resolve('babel-plugin-named-asset-import'),
                    {
                      loaderMap: {
                        svg: {
                          ReactComponent:
                            '@svgr/webpack?-prettier,-svgo![path]',
                        },
                      },
                    },
                  ],
                ],
                // This is a feature of `babel-loader` for webpack (not Babel itself).
                // It enables caching results in ./node_modules/.cache/babel-loader/
                // directory for faster rebuilds.
                cacheDirectory: true,
                cacheCompression: isEnvProduction,
                compact: isEnvProduction,
              },
            },
            // Process any JS outside of the app with Babel.
            // Unlike the application JS, we only compile the standard ES features.
            {
              test: /\.(js|mjs)$/,
              exclude: /@babel(?:\/|\\{1,2})runtime/,
              loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
              options: {
                babelrc: false,
                configFile: false,
                compact: false,
                presets: [
                  [
                    require.resolve('babel-preset-react-app/dependencies'),
                    { helpers: true },
                  ],
                ],
                cacheDirectory: true,
                cacheCompression: isEnvProduction,
                
                // If an error happens in a package, it's possible to be
                // because it was compiled. Thus, we don't want the browser
                // debugger to show the original code. Instead, the code
                // being evaluated would be much more helpful.
                sourceMaps: false,
              },
            },
            // "postcss" loader applies autoprefixer to our CSS.
            // "css" loader resolves paths in CSS and adds assets as dependencies.
            // "style" loader turns CSS into JS modules that inject <style> tags.
            // In production, we use MiniCSSExtractPlugin to extract that CSS
            // to a file, but in development "style" loader enables hot editing
            // of CSS.
            // By default we support CSS Modules with the extension .module.css
            {
              test: cssRegex,
              exclude: cssModuleRegex,
              use: getStyleLoaders({
                importLoaders: 1,
                sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
              }),
              // Don't consider CSS imports dead code even if the
              // containing package claims to have no side effects.
              // Remove this when webpack adds a warning or an error for this.
              // See https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6571
              sideEffects: true,
            },
            // Adds support for CSS Modules (https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules)
            // using the extension .module.css
            {
              test: cssModuleRegex,
              use: getStyleLoaders({
                importLoaders: 1,
                sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
                modules: true,
                getLocalIdent: getCSSModuleLocalIdent,
              }),
            },
            // Opt-in support for SASS (using .scss or .sass extensions).
            // By default we support SASS Modules with the
            // extensions .module.scss or .module.sass
            {
              test: sassRegex,
              exclude: sassModuleRegex,
              use: getStyleLoaders(
                {
                  importLoaders: 2,
                  sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
                },
                'sass-loader'
              ),
              // Don't consider CSS imports dead code even if the
              // containing package claims to have no side effects.
              // Remove this when webpack adds a warning or an error for this.
              // See https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6571
              sideEffects: true,
            },
            // Adds support for CSS Modules, but using SASS
            // using the extension .module.scss or .module.sass
            {
              test: sassModuleRegex,
              use: getStyleLoaders(
                {
                  importLoaders: 2,
                  sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
                  modules: true,
                  getLocalIdent: getCSSModuleLocalIdent,
                },
                'sass-loader'
              ),
            },
            // "file" loader makes sure those assets get served by WebpackDevServer.
            // When you `import` an asset, you get its (virtual) filename.
            // In production, they would get copied to the `build` folder.
            // This loader doesn't use a "test" so it will catch all modules
            // that fall through the other loaders.
            {
              loader: require.resolve('file-loader'),
              // Exclude `js` files to keep "css" loader working as it injects
              // its runtime that would otherwise be processed through "file" loader.
              // Also exclude `html` and `json` extensions so they get processed
              // by webpacks internal loaders.
              exclude: [/\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/, /\.html$/, /\.json$/],
              options: {
                name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
              },
            },
            // ** STOP ** Are you adding a new loader?
            // Make sure to add the new loader(s) before the "file" loader.
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
    plugins: [
      // Generates an `index.html` file with the <script> injected.
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin(
        Object.assign(
          {},
          {
            inject: true,
            template: paths.appHtml,
          },
          isEnvProduction
            ? {
                minify: {
                  removeComments: true,
                  collapseWhitespace: true,
                  removeRedundantAttributes: true,
                  useShortDoctype: true,
                  removeEmptyAttributes: true,
                  removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
                  keepClosingSlash: true,
                  minifyJS: true,
                  minifyCSS: true,
                  minifyURLs: true,
                },
              }
            : undefined
        )
      ),
      // Inlines the webpack runtime script. This script is too small to warrant
      // a network request.
      isEnvProduction &&
        shouldInlineRuntimeChunk &&
        new InlineChunkHtmlPlugin(HtmlWebpackPlugin, [/runtime~.+[.]js/]),
      // Makes some environment variables available in index.html.
      // The public URL is available as %PUBLIC_URL% in index.html, e.g.:
      // <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
      // In production, it will be an empty string unless you specify "homepage"
      // in `package.json`, in which case it will be the pathname of that URL.
      // In development, this will be an empty string.
      new InterpolateHtmlPlugin(HtmlWebpackPlugin, env.raw),
      // This gives some necessary context to module not found errors, such as
      // the requesting resource.
      new ModuleNotFoundPlugin(paths.appPath),
      // Makes some environment variables available to the JS code, for example:
      // if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') { ... }. See `./env.js`.
      // It is absolutely essential that NODE_ENV is set to production
      // during a production build.
      // Otherwise React will be compiled in the very slow development mode.
      new webpack.DefinePlugin(env.stringified),
      // This is necessary to emit hot updates (currently CSS only):
      isEnvDevelopment && new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
      // Watcher doesn't work well if you mistype casing in a path so we use
      // a plugin that prints an error when you attempt to do this.
      // See https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/240
      isEnvDevelopment && new CaseSensitivePathsPlugin(),
      // If you require a missing module and then `npm install` it, you still have
      // to restart the development server for Webpack to discover it. This plugin
      // makes the discovery automatic so you don't have to restart.
      // See https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/186
      isEnvDevelopment &&
        new WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin(paths.appNodeModules),
      isEnvProduction &&
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
          // Options similar to the same options in webpackOptions.output
          // both options are optional
          filename: 'static/css/[name].[contenthash:8].css',
          chunkFilename: 'static/css/[name].[contenthash:8].chunk.css',
        }),
      // Generate a manifest file which contains a mapping of all asset filenames
      // to their corresponding output file so that tools can pick it up without
      // having to parse `index.html`.
      new ManifestPlugin({
        fileName: 'asset-manifest.json',
        publicPath: publicPath,
      }),
      // Moment.js is an extremely popular library that bundles large locale files
      // by default due to how Webpack interprets its code. This is a practical
      // solution that requires the user to opt into importing specific locales.
      // https://github.com/jmblog/how-to-optimize-momentjs-with-webpack
      // You can remove this if you don't use Moment.js:
      new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/),
      // Generate a service worker script that will precache, and keep up to date,
      // the HTML & assets that are part of the Webpack build.
      isEnvProduction &&
        new WorkboxWebpackPlugin.GenerateSW({
          clientsClaim: true,
          exclude: [/\.map$/, /asset-manifest\.json$/],
          importWorkboxFrom: 'cdn',
          navigateFallback: publicUrl + '/index.html',
          navigateFallbackBlacklist: [
            // Exclude URLs starting with /_, as they're likely an API call
            new RegExp('^/_'),
            // Exclude URLs containing a dot, as they're likely a resource in
            // public/ and not a SPA route
            new RegExp('/[^/]+\\.[^/]+$'),
          ],
        }),
      // TypeScript type checking
      useTypeScript &&
        new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin({
          typescript: resolve.sync('typescript', {
            basedir: paths.appNodeModules,
          }),
          async: false,
          checkSyntacticErrors: true,
          tsconfig: paths.appTsConfig,
          compilerOptions: {
            module: 'esnext',
            moduleResolution: 'node',
            resolveJsonModule: true,
            isolatedModules: true,
            noEmit: true,
            jsx: 'preserve',
          },
          reportFiles: [
            '**',
            '!**/*.json',
            '!**/__tests__/**',
            '!**/?(*.)(spec|test).*',
            '!**/src/setupProxy.*',
            '!**/src/setupTests.*',
          ],
          watch: paths.appSrc,
          silent: true,
          formatter: typescriptFormatter,
        }),
    ].filter(Boolean),
    // Some libraries import Node modules but don't use them in the browser.
    // Tell Webpack to provide empty mocks for them so importing them works.
    node: {
      dgram: 'empty',
      fs: 'empty',
      net: 'empty',
      tls: 'empty',
      child_process: 'empty',
    },
    // Turn off performance processing because we utilize
    // our own hints via the FileSizeReporter
    performance: false,
  };
};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create React App overwrites your configurations to enforce isolatedModules. You have to either eject or change it in node-modules/react-scripts (not recommended).

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me (in VS Code in a React project):  in your tsconfig.json file (at the root level of my project), just set isolatedModules to false as shown below:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": false,   <=====================
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "preserve"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Comment: its not work. babel override the file and change the flag value

Comment: This not work, when compile ts, it override the tsconfig file and change isolatedModules to  true